# QGIS crashes when iterating twice on a layer?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, iterator

I am facing an issue for the first time and can not manage to find out what's wrong?

I am trying to write a function that takes in input the line ID, finds the node at the end of the line. Then looks for the lines at the origin of the found node.

```
Def find(id):    
    canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()

    lyrs = dict((k.name(), i) for (i, k) in enumerate(canvas.layers()))
    LayerC = canvas.layer(lyrs['Lines'])
    LayerB = canvas.layer(lyrs['Nodes'])
    list=[]
    for line in LayerC.getFeatures():
       if line.id() == id:
          geom1 = line.geometry()
          xy_line = geom1.asPolyline()
          xy_O = xy_line[0]
          xy_E = xy_line[len(xy_line) - 1]

          listnodes = LayerB.getFeatures()
          for featN in listnodes:
            geomN = featN.geometry()
            xy_N = geomN.asPoint()

            if xy_N == xy_E:
                for line2 in LayerC.getFeatures():
                     geom2 = line2.geometry()
                     xy_line2 = geom2.asPolyline()
                     xy_O2 = xy_line2[0]
                     xy_E2 = xy_line2[len(xy_line2) - 1]

                     if xy_N == xy_O2:
                          list.append(line2.id())
        return list
```

The code crashes when iterating for the second time on `LayerC`.
I am running this on Windows x64 with the version 2.14.3

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What do you mean by crash?  Any python error or exception? Can you port a picture of your lines and nodes to better understand what you try to do

Comment: Hi, no error. The code stops running and Qgis freezes.

Comment: How do you develop your script? Are you using an exernal IDE as PyDev and the debug plugin of qgis ? Or are you developing as old style under python console ?

Comment: I use notepad++ and save as .py file. The objective is to build a plugin but first I test it from the python console

Comment: Just a clue, i didnot try for now,can you try to use another instance for the second loop . I mean call LayerC2 as layer lines.

Comment: Yes I already tried that with no success.
Finally, I decided to stock my attributes in a multidimensional list and iterate over it.